# One hot encoding with different unique value in Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, one-hot-encoding, unique-values

Basically this is my problem: I'm trying to implement a LSH solution with spark, but to do that I need that both Training and Test have the same columns in the same order.

Second problem, I have different unique values in training and test.

For example one column in the train can have 3 unique values

```
col
a
b
c
```

and when I apply OHE

```
a  b  c
1  0  0
0  1  0
0  0  1
```

But my Test can be for example

```
col
a
e
f
```

so applying OHE

```
a  e  f
1  0  0
0  1  0
0  0  1
```

But what I would like to see in the test is

```
a  b  c
1  0  0
0  0  0
0  0  0
```

How can I achieve this in spark?
I don't care about the unique values present in the test dataset, but I care about what is in the training and not in the test.

Comment: [`OneHotEncoder`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.feature.OneHotEncoder.html) has a parameter *handleInvalid='keep'* to handle invalid catagories for predictions.